# MySQL group by timestamp difference

Tags: date, group-by, mariadb, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I need to write mysql query which will group results by difference between timestamps.
Is it possible?
I have table with locations and every row has created_at (timestamp) and I want to group results by difference > 1min.
Example:

```
id | lat | lng | created_at
1. | ... | ... | 2020-05-03 06:11:35
2. | ... | ... | 2020-05-03 06:11:37
3. | ... | ... | 2020-05-03 06:11:46
4. | ... | ... | 2020-05-03 06:12:48
5. | ... | ... | 2020-05-03 06:12:52
```

Result of this data should be 2 groups (1,2,3) and (4,5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you actually want. If youw want to group together records that belong to the same minute, regardless of the difference with the previous record, then simple aggregation is enough:

```
select 
    date_format(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') date_minute,
    min(id) min_id, 
    max(id) max_id, 
    min(created_at) min_created_at, 
    max(created_at) max_created_at,
    count(*) no_records
from mytable
group by date_minute
```

On the other hand, if you want to build groups of consecutive records that have less than 1 minute gap in between, this is a gaps and islands problem. Here is on way to solve it using window functions (available in MySQL 8.0):

```
select 
    min(id) min_id, 
    max(id) max_id, 
    min(created_at) min_created_at, 
    max(created_at) max_created_at,
    count(*) no_records
from (
    select
        t.*,
        sum(case when created_at < lag_created_at + interval 1 minute then 0 else 1 end) 
            over(order by created_at) grp
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            lag(created_at) over(order by created_at) lag_created_at
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by grp
```

Comment: I need to build groups of consecutive records. Trying you code but it throws syntax error.
My mysql version is: 10.1.44-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Comment: @general666 . . . You should update your version of MariaDB.  This is quite challenging without window functions.

Comment: @general666: window functions are available starting Maria DB 10.3. As commented by Gordon Linoff, this problem is very hard to solve without window functions.

Comment: An alternative for the `DATE_FORMAT(...)` is `LEFT(created_at, 16)` in this case.